# A <Router> may have only one child element.tried everything

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

well I am doing a simple navbar with react router i have read other threads with this problem but none seems to solve the issue

```js
mport React, { Component } from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Route from "react-router-dom/Route";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Switch from "react-router-dom/Switch";
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Navbar />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />{" "}
        </Switch>{" "}
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am also getting those {" "} but I don't know why .It seems because of prettier or ESLint .if someone has solution to these also please help  .i think this is the root of the problem.
user settings for it are:

```js
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "prettier.disableLanguages": ["js"],
  "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
  "editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
  "git.autofetch": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
 
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: The problem occurs because of the second `{ " " }`. It is considered as a child element this is why you are getting the error. Probably, you have space there and your `prettier` (if you use) or `linter` converts this space into `{ " " }`. So, either clean this space or change your configuration. I'm not quite sure it solves your issue but you can check [this conversation](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4223).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to wrap everything in BrowserRouter with Fragment component?
This is a dummy component that will not produce any html tags:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
...
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          </Fragment>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**Update:**
Another steps I would take to find the root of the problem:

1. check if you have the latest package for react-router
2. temporary replace Switch with Fragment like I did for a small project

[image]

3. make new app with create-react-app and move src folder and package.json there - ensure that your code is ok

Comment: I think the fragment needs to be inside <Switch> rather than <BrowserRouter>